# LED8102S Driver Circuit

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, led-driver

I have what I thought was a pretty simple low-side LED driver circuit based on the [STLED8102S IC](https://www.st.com/en/power-management/led8102s.html).  The supply voltage to the circuit is 12VAC nominal (15VAC measured), rectified & smoothed to 15VDC for the LED common rail, and then regulated to 5VDC via an [MC7805](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc7800-d.pdf) for the 8102 Vdd.  I have the current setting resistor R_EXT set to 390Ohm for approx 50mA.

The issue I'm having is that the 7805 is only making about .3-.5VDC and just cooks itself in a minute or two.  The demand on the 5V side should only be about 14-16mA according to the 8102 datasheet, and the 8102 should only be driving 400mA via the rectified 15VDC which is well within the capabilities of the [ABS210](https://www.diodes.com/part/view/ABS210/) bridge rectifier.  I'm guessing that the 7805 voltage is so low and the device so hot because there is excessive current through it, but I can't see where.

I'm currently testing the circuit with only 1 or 2 of the driver circuits connected, which is also OK according to the datasheet.  My circuit (drawing attached) is essentially the typical application circuit in Fig 8 of the datasheet.  Each output has three Luxeon 3535L LEDs in series for a combined forward voltage of about 9V, and the max continuous current through the LEDs is 200mA - although like I previously mentioned I have the driver set to sink 50mA.

I've checked for a problem with the board (short) re: the 7805 but there is no continuity between any of the 3 legs.  Any ideas for what might be the issue here?

[image]

Here's the layout for the 7805 -> 8102 area.  5V is run on bottom layer to the 8102.  After removing the 8102, 5VDC is present at the 5V test pad.

[image]

Here's the Top layer for completeness.  The pinout is consistent with Figure 1 in the 8102 Datasheet.

[image]

Comment: I assume you have checked this, but considering your circuit, if you disconnect all driver circuits (no load), does the 7805 regulate correctly to 5V at its output? (Also assuming you read the datasheet of the 7805 regarding any required input/output stability capacitors)

Comment: @johnEE - The 7805 was NOT making 5V, then I pulled the 8102 off of the board and isolated the 7805 and all the sudden it was making 5V.  Solder looked good on the 8102 before I pulled it.  Not sure what else it might be.  Adding the PCB layout to the OP above.

Comment: The output pad of the 7805 looks shorted to GND, there is no insulation gap around it.

Comment: If it regulates to 5V with no load, it might be what @TonyStewartEE75 mentioned. However, I think you should try using the 8102 again but this time with 5V from a lab power supply; if an absurd current is drawn from the supply, I would bet on a blown 8102.

Comment: Did it ever work? or go into thermal shutdown with 12V?  The schematic shows L-N going into bridge!  You have too much headroom for the 7805 with 7V drop  * 0.4A=3.5W seems a bit too much for this heatsink.  but you only tested 2 channels.  A 7VAC might have been better.  Use diode test on 8102 on Vcc to gnd isolated.

Comment: recheck layout for correct pins on 5V and gnd

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - The L-N are just netports from the 12VAC in, they are not mains.  The 7V drop across the 7805 is correct, but it is only supplying the 8201 with 14-16mA Vdd->GND.  The rectified 12V (nominal) @ .4A is supplied by the bridge and sunk by the 8102 through the LEDs.  I know the 7V drop for the 7805 would be a lot if it were supplying high current, but it should not be - again only the 14-16mA for the 8201 logic.  It is behaving as if it's supplying a lot of current though.  I haven't had a chance yet to swap out the 8102 for a new one or diode test in.

Comment: @Jens - It is not.  The 7805 is mounted on the top layer but we're looking at the bottom layer of the board here because that's where the 5V traces live.  I also tested continuity between all three pads on my proto boards and there is no continuity.  That was my first thought though!

Comment: IC failures with proper distribution and handling are rare as they are 100% tested. So the root cause is in the nitty-gritty details of your design/assembly process.  Photos of both sides might illuminate more info. Be sure to solder with EOS /ESD safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and started from scratch and built the board back up from the power supply, to the 5V regulator, and then finally the 8102 - and all was well!  My best guess is that there was a short in/under the 8102 that I couldn't see under magnified visual inspection. I used a stencil for the board to do a respectable job soldering the fine pitch leads on that IC, but I guess I failed.

Another lesson learned, and lots of good input from all of you - much appreciated. Thanks!